# Is there any way to expand width of container div when it is height get reduced?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a toolbar with multiple column using only HTML and CSS (No js)
I have following html structure:

```
<ul class="toolbar">
   <li><a class="tool">t1</a></li>
   <li><a class="tool">t2</a></li>
   <li><a class="tool">t3</a></li>
   <li><a class="tool">t4</a></li>
   <li><a class="tool">t5</a></li>
  <li><a class="tool">t6</a></li>
  <li><a class="tool">t7</a></li>
  <li><a class="tool">t8</a></li>
  <li><a class="tool">t9</a></li>
</ul
```

**and css as below:**

```
.toolbar{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:40px
}
.toolbar li{
  background-color:grey;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  line-height:40px;
  list-style-type:none; 
  text-align:center;
  width:38px; 
}
```

Currently I have put a fixed width 40px for the .toolbar. The toolbar will change to 2 column when this width to 80px.

I want to remove this fixed width 40px from .toolbar div. and need to make it support multiple columns. Also I need to wrap the tools to multiple columns when window height decreases. The ordering of toolbar for differrent tool length will be as below:

**3 column:**

1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9

10 11 12

**2Column:**

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

**1 column:**

1

2

3

4

5

I need a pure CSS solution .Could anybody please help

See the Pen [Multiple columns toolbar](http://codepen.io/ajineshravi/pen/wGQWzm/) by ajineshravi ([@ajineshravi](http://codepen.io/ajineshravi)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Comment: so do you want the content to define the column size and do you want to have a max-width and/or min-width.

Comment: Yes, I want to wrap the tools to multiple columns according to screen height. and also need to keep the order horizontally . eg. second tool should render at right side of 1st tool if there are two columns. No maximum width..  minimum width is 1 tool width (40px).

Number of columns should be according to screen height and number of tools rendered.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   html,body{
 height:100%;
}
.toolbar{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
min-width:40px;
}
a{
  background-color:grey;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  display:block;
  line-height:40px;
  list-style-type:none; 
  text-align:center;
  width:38px; 
}
```

Comment: It should be in single column if the number of tools are less to accommodate in single column.

Comment: Sorry, It is not wrapping to next column while resizing window.  Also order should be left to right as

If two column:

t1 and t2 in first line if it is two column and t3 and t4 in second line

If three Column:

t1,t2 and t3 should be in First column  and t4, t5 and t6 should be in second column

Comment: this is how u want it rite? vertical columns..correct?